# Did Rama and Ravana agree to rules of war, as was done in the Mahabharata?

Tags: rama, dharma, ravana, war

I think Ravana says Rakshasas don't have dharmic rules of war.  Did Ravana's side fight adharmically all the time, or did they show fair play on occasion?

Was destroying Indrajit's Yagna to prevent him from acquiring more powers Dharmic?